# Creating image with javacv

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I want to create an empty image which means a white background image where a have selected some images from another image and i want to add these images to the created empty one howe can i apply that using javacv

this is my part of my code for selecting images from a loaded one

```
IplImage originalImage = cvLoadImage("test/test_11.jpg");

        // We need a grayscale image in order to do the recognition, so we
        // create a new image of the same size as the original one.
        IplImage resultImage = IplImage.create(originalImage.width(),
                originalImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        /* convert RGB image we loaded into an grey image */
        cvCvtColor(originalImage, resultImage , CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvSaveImage("test/test_12.jpg", cvtColorImage);

        /* smooth(blur) the above image, using gaussian blur method */
        cvSmooth(resultImage , resultImage , CV_GAUSSIAN, 7);

        /*
         * Then we can threshold the blurred image. Instead of normal
         * thresholding i've used adaptive thresholding for better results. In
         * adaptive thresholding it calculates threshold values for each pixel
         * on image by looking at pixels surrounding that pixel.
         */
        cvAdaptiveThreshold(resultImage , resultImage , 255,
                CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 5);


        /*
         * Then comes the most important part. It is finding contours in
         * thresholded image. Code given below will find all the contours in the
         * above image and store them to dynamic data structure CvSeq contours.
         * Function cvFindContours() will do the job for us and it will return
         * the number of contours detected in the image.
         */
        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSeq contours = new CvContour(null);
        int noOfContors = cvFindContours(resultImage , storage, contours,
                Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP,
                CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, new CvPoint(0, 0));

        /*
         * If we use the above image, function will detect x contours in above
         * image. Then we have to iterate through the data structure and filter
         * out objects we need. So i used a little trick here. I ignored
         * contours with bounding box with area greater than 1200 and less than
         * 3000. This will leave 10 contours out of x.
         */
        CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();

        int count = 1;
        Random rand = new Random();
        CvPoint p1 = new CvPoint(0, 0), p2 = new CvPoint(0, 0);

        for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {

            Color randomColor = new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(),
                    rand.nextFloat());
            CvScalar color = CV_RGB(randomColor.getRed(),
                    randomColor.getGreen(), randomColor.getBlue());
            CvRect sq = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);
            double prop = (double) (sq.width()) / sq.height();

            if (sq.width() > 15)
                if (prop > 0 && prop < 3) {
                    System.out.println(sq.width() + " " + sq.height() + " "
                            + prop);

                    p1.x(sq.x());
                    p2.x(sq.x() + sq.width());
                    p1.y(sq.y());
                    p2.y(sq.y() + sq.height());
                    cvRectangle(resultImage , p1, p2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 2, 8,
                            0);
//                  cvDrawContours(resultImage , ptr, color, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0),
//                          -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0, 0));
                    count++;
                }

        }
        System.out.println("Count =" + (count - 1));
        cvSaveImage("test/test_16.jpg", resultImage );
    }
```

by this code in the for looping i am getting a list of images i want to add these images to a new empty image

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, may be you wanted to create an image using

```
IplImage sumImage = IplImage.create(originalImage.width(),
            originalImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

and set the contents to zero

```
cvSetZero(sumImage); //Adding to black Image may be correct than white image.
```

And then use

```
    cvAdd(sumImage, resultImage, sumImage) in your for loop.
```

Comment: cvAdd takes 4 parameters and not 3 void cvAdd(const CvArr* src1, const CvArr* src2, CvArr* dst, const CvArr* mask=NULL) where src.channel() must be = dst.channel() and the same for size so how can be the added src and the destination have same size and i want to add random images with random sizes

Comment: For cvAdd the last parameter is optional. you may not neet it. and for size, you can set the ROI correspondingly and add. 
For ex: 
size of img1 is 100 X 100

Comment: For ex: 
size of img1 is 100 X 100
size of img2 is 50 X 50
 you want to add img2 to img1 in thd middle. 
CvRect R1(25,25,50,50);
cvSetImageROI(img1,R1);
cvAdd(img1,img2,img1): should work. because the effective size of img1 and img2 is same.

Comment: ok i got what you mean but i want to add img2 behind img1 and not on it where i need to add a sequence of images all are behind each other so how can i apply this

Comment: I suppose you want to add the new image in the sequence if the sum image is already not filled at that pixel. You can achieve this using the sumimage itself as mask (the 4th parameter in cvAdd). 
If I did not get you correctly, give an example of input and results.

Comment: i dont know what examples to write but what i mean is that i have 2 images img1 and img2. whats i concluded from cvAdd is that it adds img1 on img2 where it is just copying img2 on img1 where it is not add because img1 is disappearing at all. So i want to add img1 and img2 to another image where img1 is just behind img2 and not on it